# What is the most upvoted comment?

Tags: discussion, comment, voting, up-votes, reference-request

You can see that the most upvoted question in the main Math Stack Exchange site also has many [upvoted comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain) with one even having over 200 comment upvotes. So then what is the most upvoted comment in MSE? How about in any of the Stack Exchange sites, including both main and meta? Here are the color tiers based on the number of votes turning from a grey to orange:

Gray=1 to 4 upvotes:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Brown=5 to around 14 upvotes:

[image]

Orange=15 to around 30 upvotes

[image]

Light Orange=31+ upvotes:

[image]

Perhaps there exists a special comment with 400+ upvotes somewhere in MSE or in any of the forums, also including the metas? It may be possible a new color is unlocked when there are more than 300 votes? I have never seen a question similar to this one on any other site and I would really love to know. I also believe that others are curious too. I may have made the wrong guesses for the comment vote colors, so please correct me and give me feedback!

$\large{\text{Results:}}$

As you may have guessed, Stack Overflow has the most [upvoted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304895/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-from-remote-to-local-using-scp/11304926#11304926) as of writing this post is a  supernova comment currently with 1629 votes. It has [this comic](https://xkcd.com/1168/) link. This is the [source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67902/top-100-most-upvoted-comments). Perhaps there is a more popular comment in another Stack Exchange/ Overflow site?:

[image]

Comment: The easiest way to find such comments is via the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/57246/comment-leaderboard) is a query which finds the most-upvoted comments on a site, set to math.SE. The current leader is the second comment on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4) with 755 votes. On my monitor, it appears that the color doesn't change much between 33 and 755, so it would be reasonable to assume this is the final color.

Comment: @KReiser I saw this post before. Thanks! Do you know what is the highest upvoted comment in all of stack Exchange, including metas and overflow sites? I suspect another highly rated post will have higher upvoted comment as Stack exchange is bigger. Then again another overflow/stack exchange site, meta or not, may have a new record.

Comment: That question, Tyma, might be asked on Meta.se, but I'm not a fan of trivial trivia, and this sentiment is likely held on meta.se as well.

Comment: Stack exchange is *not* a forum.

Comment: @TymaGaidash the question is still up because it is a valid question. I am not saying the question is bad. What I’m saying is that in the post you say “Perhaps there exists a special comment with 400+ upvotes somewhere in MSE or in any of the forums, also including the metas?” And I just wanted to nitpick and say [stack exchange is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums) :)

Comment: A similar question was recently posted on Math Overflow Meta: [How to find highly upvoted comments?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5430)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you can find things like this using [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). Here is a query looking for the most upvoted comments [on the main site](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1418825/comments-with-highest-score?num=500) and [on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1418825/comments-with-highest-score?num=500). And here is a similar query [for Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1440263/comments-with-highest-score-above-min). (SO has many comments - to make the query faster I have added the condition to check only the comments above certain score.)

You have also asked for top comments network-wide. ("How about in any of the Stack Exchange sites, including both main and meta?") It is probably not surprising that top comments are dominated by Stack Overflow, see [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1440256/comments-with-highest-score-multisite).

This is what you get [after omitting SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1440257/comments-with-highest-score-multisite-not-so). If we ignore Stack Overflow, there are no longer comments with score above 1000. In the top 10, there are currently four comments from Meta Stack Exchange and three comments from Math Stack Exchange.

Some similar SEDE queries have been posted also here: [Can I view a list of my “great comments”, perhaps in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130906#130908)

As far as colors of the vote counts are concerned, you can check the FAQ post on Meta Stack Overflow: [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281740#281741)

> View counts and comment scores both have dynamic text color based on the value they represent, going from ordinary gray to bright orange. Class names are `cool`, `warm`, `hot`, and `supernova`.

The exact values are mentioned in this animuson's post: [What is a cool comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284403#284404)

> **0–4:** "cool" class
> **5–15:** "warm" class
> **16–30:** "hot" class
> **31+:** "supernova" class